# Check if a file transferred successfully in WinSCP, when using the Session.PutFile function

Tags: c#, .net, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to send some files to a remote FTP server, and I need to make sure the files actually make it there before I continue my code.

Is there a way to check if the file transferred successfully using the `Session.PutFile` method? It doesn't have the `TransferOperationResult` return type that `Session.PutFiles` does, and in fact returns `void`.

If at all possible, I would like to handle the files as `Stream` objects in memory, rather than saving them locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Session.PutFile` raises an exception, if any error occurs.

If it does not raise any exception, the upload was successful.